# How to move entire folder to the new path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to move the whole folder -with its entire files- to a new path. (in the same filesystem) All the examples I looked at were on moving just a single file, not an entire folder. How can I achieve this?

current folder structure:

```
-> 35 (folder)
   -> 1 (folder)
      -> a.jpg
      -> b.txt
      -> c.mp3
   -> 2 (folder)
      -> x.jpg
      -> y.txt
      -> z.mp3
.
.
.
```

```
source path: /storage/0EFD-3C1E/35
destination path: /storage/0EFD-3C1E/Android/data/com.my.app/files
```

Comment: `Directory` class has `rename()` function, did you try it?

Comment: I try to use it like that: wait Directory(sourcePath).rename(destPath); but it returns OS Error: Cross-device link, errno = 18

Comment: so it seems they are not in the same filesystem as you said - in this case you have to recursively copy all the files and folders